# Ghostscript: convert a PDF with a picture from RGB to Gray

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, cmyk

I used to following code to convert a pdf with a rgb picture:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
   -dPDFSETTINGS="/prepress" \
   \
   -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
   \
   -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
   -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
   -dMonoImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
   \
   -dDownsampleColorImages=false \
   -dDownsampleGrayImages=false \
   -dDownsampleMonoImages=false \
   \
   \
   -sOutputFile=$4 \
   -f "$1"
```

Using this code does not change to color mode of that picure.

If a convert the included picture to gray with gs  (it is a pdf modified with inkscape and saved as rgb) before creating the pdf using latex it works.

The used GS-version is 9.26.
Links for used data:

- the included picture: [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/upn1dxb4b6e8r51/Verbunddichte_3-inkscape.pdf?dl=0)
- with latex created: 
  [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/430pijwogeoixws/page-24.pdf?dl=0)
- to gray converted pdf which makes the problem: 
  [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bb0rpqm28uyee0u/page-24-gray-all.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Put the PDF file somewhere public (eg DropBox) and suppl ya link here. You should also state the version of Ghostscript you are using. If I were you I would drop hte -dPDFSETTINGS and just apply the controls you want. PDFSETTINGS changes upwards of 60 different configuration options all at once, while debugging at least its better to change as few things as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I edited the Questions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the 'gray converted pdf' file I see that the content is entirely in DeviceGray. So why do you think that it isn't ? How are you determining 'the colour mode' ?

The PDF file does contain transparency (pointlessly, but that's Cairo for you) and that has a DeviceRGB blending mode. That's not something that Ghostscript's pdfwrite can change, if it changed the blending mode then Bad Things might happen to the output.

Comment: I used the inkcov-device of gs:  gs -q -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov page-24-gray-all.pdf which shows: 0.04940  0.04940  0.04940  0.04277 CMYK OK

Comment: About transparency I am a bit confused. The picture does not have transparency (checked with Acrobat 8), the with latex created pdf has transparency in that picture. How can I check with gs? (my installation does not have the pdf_info.ps file) I general I would like to avoid transparency because I need prepress files.

Comment: inkcov doesn't tell you what the **original** colour space was. What it tells you is, when printed to a CMYK device, how much of each process colour is used. That means that the Gray values are converted to CIE colour space, and then to CMYK space. Depending on the ICC profiles being used that can, and usually does, result in something other than C=M=Y=0 and gray%K. You can't reliably use it to tell you anything about the colour space of the original file I'm afraid

Comment: The file Verbunddichte_3-inkscape.pdf contains an ExtGState dictionary with CA and ca values (Constant alpha). The page object additionally contains a transparency Group dictionary with a DeviceRGB blending space (CS). As I said, the transparency has no actual effect, since teh CA values are 1 (100%, ie opaque) but nevertheless they **are** transparency directives. The pdfwrite device cannot know at the page definition, that the transparency is pointless, so it has to include it in its own output.

Comment: If pdfinfo.ps has not been included in the distribution you are using you should complain to the package maintainer. You can get a copy by picking up the source from the source tarball on the Ghostscript web site, or by cloning the Git repository. Note that the transparency in this file has **no** effect, but at the time the first operation is detected (on opening the page) there is no way for the outptu device to know that, so it has to include the page level transparency group.

Comment: You are right inkconv only tells the values printed to CMYK device. But if I get gs: gs -q -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov page-24-gray-all.pdf which shows: 0.04940 0.04940 0.04940 0.04277 CMYK OK  then I think it can not be a DeviceGray. Which tool (linux) do you you for check of the original colour space?

Comment: I am still confused about transparency because Acrobat 8 did not tell about transparency in the file. How do you check transparency? I can not convert files with transparency with gs, right?

Comment: I check transparency the same way I check the original colour space, I read the actual PDF file contents. I can assure you the PDF file does contain transparency, though as I said, the transparency has **no effect** (I've said this several times). I don't know what you mean when you discuss the inkcov devioce, it does not tell you **anything** about the original colour space. All it tells you is what the colours will be on a CMYK device.

Comment: If the colour conversion from grey to CIE XYZ to CMYK does not result in pure K (which it absolutely need not do) then what you will see is 'rich black'. This depends utterly on the Gray ICC profile you are using. You are using the term 'convert' very liberally. Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device are perfectly capable of processing the PDF file and producing a new one. Your original question was why your 'RGB' 'picture' didn't change into DeviceGray, to which the answer is 'because it was already Gray not RGB. If you haev another question, please start a new question.